# Django admin site : Help needed

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was trying to customize the djando admin.py.I wanted to register a model `Contribution` in a class `ContributionAdmin`.In the admin interface,I needed to print a field `application_number` number from another model `Subscriber`.There is a Foreign key relationship with the models.How to do this?

admin.py

```
class ContributionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','nlcc','subscriber','date','receipt_number','amount', 'status')
    list_filter =  ('nlcc',)
    search_fields = ('receipt_number',)
    exclude = ('subscriber',)
admin.site.register(models.Contribution, ContributionAdmin)
```

models.py:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
   nlcc = models.ForeignKey(NLCC)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SUBSCRIBER_TYPE)
   application_date =  models.DateField(null=True)
   application_number =  models.IntegerField()
   staff_agent = models.ForeignKey(StaffAgent, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Contribution(models.Model):
   nlcc = models.ForeignKey(NLCC)
   subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber)
   staff_agent = models.ForeignKey(StaffAgent, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   date = models.DateField(null=True)
   initial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   govt =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
   receipt_number = models.BigIntegerField()
   amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CONTRIBUTION_STATUS)
   status_date = models.DateField(null=True)
   deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   package = models.ForeignKey('CourierPackage', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='contribution')
```

or else is there any way to return the `Subscriber` name rather than object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method which will return the desired fields and add the name of this method to the `list_display`:

```
class ContributionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id','nlcc','subscriber','application_number',
                    'date','receipt_number','amount', 'status')    

    def application_number(self, obj):
        return obj.subscriber.application_number
    application_number.short_description = "Subscriber's Application Number"
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to see the `name` and the `application_number` in the select box for `subscriber` field then the simplest solution is to define the `__unicode__` method of the `Subscriber` model:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s' % (self.name, self.application_number)
```

**UPDATE 2**: If the number of subscribers is too long then you can use the [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) property:

```
class ContributionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('subscriber', )
```

**UPDATE 3**: To make this field read-only use the [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
class ContributionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('subscriber', )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.but, I dont want to display the application number in the list.Soadding the method to ' list_display ' is not usefull. Is there any way I could return subscriber name rather than object?

Comment: Hm, where you want to display it?

Comment: I want to display it on the edit of the list view.Is there any way I could return subscriber name rather than object?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you right.  See the updated answer,

Comment: Actually, class ContributionAdmin returns a list of contributions.If I try to edit a single entry ,It will take so much time to load,since the field subscriber is a dropdown list showing the objects of table subscriber.If I could display the name of subscriber in a textbox rather than displaying the object,that will be better.

Comment: How would you _change_ the subscriber of a contribution then?